# Roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ are from the orbit of $\alpha$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, proof-explanation, irreducible-polynomials

I already understand t.gunn's proof (below) but got me thinking how did he come up with the idea? I mean, why did he know that the roots of the minimal polynomial had to be elements from here $G\cdot\alpha$ (the orbit of $\alpha)?$

Proposition: If $\mathbf K:\mathbf F<\infty,$ and is Galois, then it is normal and separable.

**Proof:**
(summary of t.gunn's proof  :)

Let $\alpha\in\mathbf K.$

The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is

$$ f_\alpha(x) := \prod_{\beta \in G \cdot \alpha} (x - \beta). $$
Indeed:

First, note that $f_\alpha(\alpha) = 0$, which follows since $\alpha = \operatorname{id}(\alpha) \in G \cdot \alpha$.

- Second, note that $f_\alpha \in \mathbf{F}[x]$,
- Third note that $f_\alpha$ is minimal. Indeed if $f(\alpha) = 0$ then $f(\sigma(\alpha)) = \sigma(f(\alpha)) = \sigma(0) = 0$ for all $\sigma \in G$. Thus $\sigma(\alpha)$ is a root for all $\sigma \in G$. Thus $f_\alpha \mid f$.

Finally, we note that $f_\alpha$ splits over $\mathbf{K}$ and is separable, by construction.

Comment: must be a hard explanation..

Comment: If I got it right at the heart of your question are the [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas). The coefficients of, for example, the polynomial $(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)$ are symmetric under all permutations of the zeros $\alpha_i,i=1,2,3$. Because the Galois group permutes the roots, those symmetric functions are invariant under $G$, hence belong to the fixed field. Anyway, this idea permeates all Galois theory, and is the first thing to look at. That's why T. Gunn had no difficulties.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm not sure If I understand well your comment, you say that the coefficients of $(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)=x^3-(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)x^2+\alpha_1\alpha_2x-\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3$ are symmetric under all permutations of the roots, I think it is because instead of having this $(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)$ we can have this $(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_3)$ thus the coefficients are symmetric. Am I correct?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think there is a typo when you say 'symmetric functions', I think you mean 'symmetric coefficients'

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen On the other hand, I think a continuation of your comment would be: hence 'those symmetric functions' are in $\mathbf F$. However I don't know what I can conclude with that, I mean I don't see a relation between this and my question.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I already know that the roots of the minimal polynomial are in $\mathbf F$, so they are also in the fixed field of $G$, do they have relation with the 'symmetric functions' you mention above? (maybe taking the polynomial with n roots this time and not only 3)

Comment: Anne, I am more worried about whether you know that if the roots of a  polynomial are $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n$, then the "symmetric polynomials" $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots+\alpha_n$, $\ldots$,
$\alpha_1\alpha_2\cdots\alpha_n$ are 1) the coefficients (up to sign) of the said polynomial, 2) if $G$ permutes those roots, then the symmetric functions are stable under $G$, and 3) hence the coefficients are in the fixed field. Observe that it is enough for $G$ to permute the roots to get a polynomial with coefficients in the fixed field.

Comment: (cont'd) No need to assume that you started with a minimal polynomial. Any polynomial with distinct zeros will have coefficients in the fixed field when $G$ permutes those zeros. 3) Danmark er dejligt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K/F$ be a finite Galois extension, and let $G = \textrm{Gal}(K/F)$.  Let $\alpha \in K$, and let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$.  Let $\Phi$ be the set of roots of $f$.  Since $K/F$ is normal, $\Phi$ is contained in $K$.  Since $K/F$ is separable, the roots of $f$ are distinct.  Thus

$$f(x) = \prod\limits_{\beta \in \Phi} (x - \beta)$$

If I understand your question, what you want to know is why the set $\Phi$ is equal to the set $G.\alpha = \{ \sigma(\alpha) : \sigma \in G \}$.

First, $G.\alpha$ is contained in $\Phi$.  This is easy to see, because if $\sigma \in G$, then $\sigma$ fixes the elements of $F$, hence the coefficients of $f$.

The converse inclusion is more difficult.  You can prove it using the two equivalent definitions of what it means for a field extension to be normal:

**Proposition**: Let $E$ be an algebraic extension of a field $F$.  The following are equivalent:

(i): If $a \in E$, then all the roots of the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$ are also in $E$.

(ii): If $\Omega$ is a field containing $E$, and $\phi: E \rightarrow \Omega$ is a homomorphism which fixes $F$ (pointwise), then $\phi$ is actually just an automorphism of $E$.

Now let $\beta$ be another root of $f$. We want to show that $\beta = \sigma(\alpha)$ for some $\sigma \in G$.  There is a unique isomorphism of fields $\phi: F(\alpha) \rightarrow F(\beta)$ which fixes $F$ pointwise and sends $\alpha$ to $\beta$.

Fix an algebraic closure $\overline{F}$ of $F$ containing $E$.  The isomorphism extension theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_extension_theorem) tells you that $\phi$ extends (in general, nonuniquely!) to homomorphism $\tilde{\phi}$ of $K$ into $\overline{F}$.  This can be proved using Zorn's lemma.

But since $K/F$ is a normal extension, $\tilde{\phi}$ is just an automorphism of $K$ fixing $F$.  In other words, $\tilde{\phi} \in G$.  And $\tilde{\phi}(\alpha) = \phi(\alpha) = \beta$, as required.